# Click a link created in a loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use pagination class to generate the following table, book titles are stored in a database

```
Title                      Action 
New book for you        Edit    Delete
How to become a manager Edit    Delete
Learn PHP in 10 minutes Edit    Delete
 < 1 2 3...10 Last>
```

Each Edit or Delete is a link created as Edit

In order to move to the edit page to update book title (edit and save into mysql table) that I need to use $_GET to retrieve $title of the correct clicked Edit link, I wonder how the href in case of a single page likely to be href='book/details?title=$title' becomes ?

Comment: Not quite sure what your question is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you generate your Markup through PHP you could do as you said.

```
foreach ($titles as $title) {
    echo '<a href="book/details?title='.$title.'">title</a>';
}
```

Otherwise you would just type the url in your href.

```
<a href="book/details?title=actualTitleName">
```

and get it serverside with

```
$_GET["title"]
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I view the second page or xth page, the url in the browser's URL adds a number of config[per_page] number after it, should this cause any problem ?

Comment: No, the values inside the querystring are separated. As long as you access your title with `$_GET["title"]` you always have that correct value. If you want to add values to your URL you haveto separate them with an `&` like `book/details?title=titlname&id=numberOfTitle`